# For Friedman Test, what are the pros and cons of different post hoc comparison method?

Tags: statistics

[scikit_posthocs](https://scikit-posthocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/) lists some post hoc pairwise comparison methods if significant results of the Friedman’s test are obtained. How do I decide which one to use? In my case, the toy dataset `df` that I have is:

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.array([[ 581.125,  366.25 ,  144.08 ,  296.575],
       [1743.4  ,  900.85 ,  338.925,  481.6  ],
       [4335.75 , 2000.1  ,  816.75 , 1236.75 ],
       [ 241.925,  540.35 ,  249.9  ,  167.5  ],
       [2822.4  , 1261.35 ,  547.025,  626.05 ],
       [ 568.32 ,  652.55 ,  277.34 ,  265.68 ]]),
    columns=['Both', 'Media Advertisement', 'Neither', 'Store Events'],
    index=['Hardware Accessories', 'Pants', 'Shoes', 'Shorts', 'Sweatshirts',
       'T-Shirts']
)
```

I first ran:

```
from scipy.stats import friedmanchisquare
print(friedmanchisquare(*df.T.values))
```

This gives me
`FriedmanchisquareResult(statistic=12.200000000000003, pvalue=0.006728522930461357)`

Now I need to do post hoc analysis, I first ran:

```
import scikit_posthocs as sp
sp.posthoc_conover_friedman(q1_friedman).style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: yellow" if x < 0.05 else "")
```

It gives me this:
[image]

I am confused which post hoc analysis approach I should choose to meet my analytic need. In [post hocs API](https://scikit-posthocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/posthocs_api/), there are `posthoc_nemenyi_friedman`, `posthoc_conover_friedman`, `posthoc_siegel_friedman` and `posthoc_miller_friedman` for me to choose from. I tried them all and they returned some conclusions that may slightly differ from one another. Statistically speaking, which approach is appropriate for my case?

Comment: Which approach is more statistically correct is not a question for the python tag.

Comment: @itprorh66 Corrected. Thanks for pointing out.